# Bootstrap site structure - re-positioning/flowing navigation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Wyq6F/ shows how I want to layout my bootstrap-based website.

The site will have a button that hides the aside and toggles the content class to fill the space.

The only thing that isn't right is the position of the navigation. At the moment, it shares a row with the branding above the row that contains the aside and the content.

What that means is in smaller displays, the navigation will flow before the aside when I need it to flow afterwards.

How should I re-position the navigation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think I've found a solution using position: absolute and margins. http://jsfiddle.net/Wyq6F/1/

It's just a matter of reverting back to position: static and removing the margins within the relevant media queries.

Unless I'm wrong and somebody has a better idea?

Thanks